# LR(k) or LALR(k) parser generator with features similar to ANTLR

Tags: parsing, parser-generator, lalr, lr-grammar

I'm currently in the process of writing a parser for some language. I've been given a grammar for this language, but this grammar has some left recursions and non-LL(*) constructs, so ANTLR doesn't do very well, even with backtracking.

Because removing these left recursions and non-LL(*) constructs is harder than it looked at first glance, I now want to try a LR(k) or LALR(k) parser generator. The higher k the better.

Can anyone recommend me a parser generator fulfilling these requirements?

- The generated parser is preferably a LR(k) parser with some high (or even arbitrary) k, or at least a LALR(k) parser with some high k.
- The generated parser is written in C or C++, and if it is written in C, it is linkable to C++-Code.
- A feature set similar to ANTLR (especially the AST rewriting) would be nice.
- Performance is *not* the most pressing issue, the generated parser is intended to
  be used on desktop machines with much memory and cpu power.

Thanks and greetings,
Jost

PS: I'm not asking because I can't google myself, but because there is no time left to test some generators myself. So please only answer if you have experience with the recommended parser generators.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have now decided to use [DParser](http://dparser.sourceforge.net/), which is a GLR-Parser generator capable of recognizing any context free language. It seems to be well programmed (look at the tests in the source distribution), but lacks a lot of the features ANTLR provides, most notably the AST-Construction tools.

As a plus, it mostly reuses ANTLRs grammar file format, which was the format my grammar is in.

Answer (score 4):

You might consider [LRSTAR](http://lrstar.tech).

I have no experience with the tool itself, but I've met the author and he seems like a pretty competent guy.  (I do build parsing engines and related technology for a living).

Comment: The LRStar description on sourceforge looks really promising, but there are no files in the svn repo, and the website does not have any content on it...

Comment: Actually, this looks more like a takedown due to legal issues or something, because it is really hard to find *any* downloadable distribution of LRStar... it is even removed on most download sites, all I could find were some windows binaries, but my working environment is a linux.

Comment: @Jost: The author of LRStar just notified me that the distribution files along with the whole site are back online. Make some backups :)

Comment: LRSTAR v 10.0 is now available.  Many improvements have been made. It can read Yacc/Bison grammars if there is no code in the grammar.

Comment: LRSTAR is at https://sourceforge.net/projects/lrstar/

Answer (score 4):

[LRSTAR 10.0](http://lrstar.tech) is available now.  On the [comparison page](http://lrstar.tech/comparison.html), there is a comparison of LRSTAR, ANTLR and Bison.  LRSTAR now reads ANTLR's style notation using the same EBNF operators (:, |, *, +, ?).  It's a C++ based system generating LR(k) parsers in C++.  The parsers do automatic AST construction and traversal. The new version 10.0 reads Yacc/Bison grammars if there is no action code in the grammar.

Comment: .org link is broken, but still available in sourceforge, thx for the info.

Comment: An older distribution is still available here: http://download.cnet.com/LRSTAR-Parser-Lexer-Generator/3001-2069_4-94121.html. It includes some sample grammars

Comment: LRSTAR is at https://sourceforge.net/projects/lrstar/